# How to conclude what Big Theta is based on the Big-O and Big-Omega values

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Say I'm told that processing time of an algorithm is Ω(n) and O(n^3) and I am asked to conclude whether Big-Theta is Θ(n^2). How would I go about answering this question?

Comment: You do not as its a wrong conclusion.

Comment: I think you will find a much better answer to your problem on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

`f(n) = Ω(n)` and `f(n) = O(n^3)` does not imply `f(n) = Θ(n^2)`.

To justify it, you can consider the following counterexamples:

- `f(n) = n`. Since for `n >= 1, n <= f(n) <= n^3`, `f(n) = Ω(n)` and `f(n) = O(n^3)` but because for `n >= 1, f(n) < n^2`, `f(n)` is not `Θ(n^2)`
- `f(n) = n^3`. Since for `n >= 1, n <= f(n) <= n^3`, `f(n) = Ω(n)` and `f(n) = O(n^3)` but because for `n >= 1, f(n) > n^2`, `f(n)` is not `Θ(n^2)`

Answer (score 0):

For the example given, the conclusion would be that it is not an accurate conclusion. In words, the explanation would be that since the algorithm is bounded above by O(n^3) and below by Omega(n), the average case running time cannot be stated based off of just those entries and the algorithm would need to be studied against multiple datasets in order to find the average case time. In general, when studying the best and worst case runtimes for algorithms, if these two are the same (meaning the algorithm is bounded on both sides by the same running time) then the Big-theta can be determined to be the same runtime. Otherwise, more information about how the algorithm is running with multiple datasets would be needed.